# Pokémon bank and home

Tags: nintendo-network-id, pokemon-bank

If I delete my bank does the Nintendo Network ID unlink? I want to transfer my Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon Pokémon to Sword and Shield.
And if I do delete my NNID, could I get games back by factory resetting?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete your NNID, you'll lose any digital content or purchases made on that account.

If you delete your Bank, the NNID will no longer be linked to that bank (because that bank does not exist), and the Pokemon inside it will no longer be available.